# How to compare two Moment.js Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, comparison, momentjs

I have an Array with Moment.js objects in a variable:

```
var feriados = function addFeriados(){
            feriados = [];
            ...
            feriados.push(moment("2016-01-01"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-02-08"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-02-09"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-03-25"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-04-21"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-05-01"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-05-26"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-09-07"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-10-12"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-11-02"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-11-15"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-12-25"));
            ...
            return feriados;
 }
```

And a function to determinate if a value is in this array:

```
function checkFeriado(data) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < allFeriados.length; i++) {
        if (allFeriados[i] == data) {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But even if i pass a `moment` object, as `checkFeriado(moment("2016-01-01"));` i'm getting false. Whats wrong with my code? Is there a best way to do this?

Entire project have jQuery and Moment.js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
moment("2016-01-01") !== moment("2016-01-01"); //true
//just like
{a:1} !== {a:1}; //true
```

[Javascript objects cannot be compared like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript), same with *moment's javascript objects*. Moment has its own implementation to check if dates are equal. use [isSame](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/)

```
moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-10-20'); // true
moment('2010-10-20').isSame(moment('2010-10-20')); // true
```

You can also use Array.filter to check this.

I wonder if you meant `fearadios = allFeradios()` as in a function call?

`allFeradios.length` doesn't sound right in your example! as it is a function name, so is feradios.

```js
var feriados = function addFeriados(){
            feriados = [];
            feriados.push(moment("2016-01-01"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-02-08"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-02-09"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-03-25"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-04-21"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-05-01"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-05-26"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-09-07"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-10-12"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-11-02"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-11-15"));
            feriados.push(moment("2016-12-25"));
            return feriados;
 } ();
function dateInArray(queryDate){
  return Boolean(feriados.filter(function(date){
     return date.isSame(queryDate);
  }).length);
  // return feriados.some(date => date.isSame(queryDate));
}
console.log(dateInArray(moment('2016-12-25')));
console.log(dateInArray(moment('2016-12-28')));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather convert moment date object to number (timeSpan) with .valueOf() method and then compare two numbers

```
function checkFeriado(data) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < allFeriados.length; i++) {
        if (allFeriados[i].valueOf() == data.value()) {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```